# mvc.net DateTime with Time part in URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, uri, modelbinders, datetime-format

I have a set of actions that are returning time-series data with-in ranges specifiable to the minute. 
They work fine with querystrings,
i.e.
`/mycontroller/myaction?from=20091201 10:31&to=20091202 10:34`
with or without URL encoded colons, but I thought it would be nice to have a pretty URL 
`/mycontroller/myaction/from-20091201 10:31/to-20091202 10:34`
but this now strikes  fear in the hear of IIS as it doesn't like colons in the URI so I get 'Bad Request' responses.

My question then, is what's a recommended/standard course of action to ensure I can keep the time in there?

Do I need to write a custom ModelBinder to parse my own datetime format? Should the actions just take strings for `from` and `to` and parse with a custom format eg `"YYYYMMDD-HHmm"`. Can I specify a custom format somewhere? If so where? Or should I just give this up as folly and stick with querystring parameters?

Oh, and I see a lot of people go on about RESTful URLs; from what I've read there's nothing that says query strings aren't RESTful - it's more about appropriate use of existing HTTP action types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right REST doesn't mean if it's its not in a folder structure its not REST.

The path structure is there to describe the resource. Querystrings can still be used to describe a filtered subset of such a resource. A date range fully qualifies as a filter criteria and should thus be perfectly RESTful being passed in as a querystring.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, So I take it from your response that you wouldn't bother to try and cram this in the URI? I think I mostly liked that as I also have URIs for a single day and that works nicely as controller/action/20091201

Comment: Yes I would leave filter properties as request strings. Even a single day if that day is not a resource i.e think: /agenda/20091201/appointments/1 versus /cars?builtAfter=20091201.